# Using Vuex stores across multiple files with WebPack

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, vuex

I'm building an web app and each page of the site will have 2 JS files in it, a "bootstrap.js" file that is basically a global file that is on every page of the site, then a custom JS file for each page. Sometimes I want these files to share the same Vuex store, but when I trigger an action on one page it doesn't reflect on the other. Does anyone know how to share a Vuex store across multiple pages?

My example is to do with a shopping cart I'm building. I want the "bootstrap.js" file to use a Vuex store used for the cart so on every page it can display how many items are in the cart. Then on some individual pages, such as the product description page, I want to use the same Vuex cart store to add items to the cart and have the total reflect in the "bootstrap.js" file. So the code looks like the below:

global_store.jsx:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import { doAsync } from '../utils/ajax'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const GET_CART_ASYNC = {
  SUCCESS: 'GET_CART_ASYNC_SUCCESS',
  FAILURE: 'GET_CART_ASYNC_FAILURE',
  PENDING: 'GET_CART_ASYNC_PENDING',
}

export let cartStore = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    cart: undefined,
    loading: false,
  },
  mutations: {
    [GET_CART_ASYNC.SUCCESS](state, data) {
      Vue.set(state, 'loading', false)
      Vue.set(state, 'cart', data)
    },
    [GET_CART_ASYNC.FAILURE](state) {
      Vue.set(state, 'loading', false)
      Vue.set(state, 'cart', null)
    },
    [GET_CART_ASYNC.PENDING](state) {
      Vue.set(state, 'loading', true)
      Vue.set(state, 'cart', null)
    }
  },
  actions: {
    manipulateCart(store, action=null) {
      doAsync(store, `/cart/api`, GET_CART_ASYNC, action)
    } 
  }
})
```

boostrap.jsx:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { mapState } from 'vuex'
import { cartStore } from '../cart/global_store'

cartStoreGlobal.dispatch('manipulateCart')

new Vue({
  el: '#cart_display',
  store: cartStore,
  computed: mapState(['cart']),
  render(h) {
    if(this.cart === null) {
      return
    }
    var num_items = this.cart.map(cart_item => cart_item.quantity).reduce((accumulator, quantity) => accumulator + quantity, 0)
    return (
      <p class="navbar-text pull-right" id="mini-cart">
        <a class="button right" href="/cart">
          <strong>{num_items} items</strong> <span>$0.00</span>
        </a>
      </p>
    )
  }
})
```

cart.jsx

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { mapState } from 'vuex'
import { CartView } from '../cart/cart_view'
import { cartStore } from '../cart/global_store'

// TODO: remove this as its already called in bootstrap.jsx, figure out how to use store singletons with webpack
cartStore.dispatch('manipulateCart')

new Vue({
  el: '#cart',
  store: cartStore,
  computed: mapState(['cart']),
  render(h) {
    return (<CartView 
      cart={this.cart} 
      remove_cb={(photo_id_to_remove) => cartStore.dispatch('manipulateCart', [{action: 'set', photo_id: photo_id_to_remove, quantity: 0}])}
    ></CartView>)
  },
})
```

So the global_store file contains the store, and bootstrap and cart are importing it. Details of "doAsync" aren't too important. I'm new to Vue and Vuex and perhaps don't fully understand how WebPack works, so any clarification and/or help getting this to work is much appreciated!

Comment: Why do you need multiple vue instances?

Comment: Well mainly I'd like to have a "global" component that is setup and bound on every single page in the bootstrap.jsx file then I'd like to have components for individual pages in their individual js files, like cart.jsx. I'd mainly like to avoid having to setup boilerplate code in every single js file for each page and instead just set it up once in the global file.

Comment: Also the two DOM bound components above are in two separate parts of the HTML. Even if I switch to having them in a single file, wouldn't I need two Vue instances to bind to different parts of the DOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this for posterity. The issue was the files were separate, meaning there were two separate instances of the store in two different files that are completely isolated from each other, which is why updating the state in one file did not effect the other. Case closed.